# Noun form of “umbilical”?

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

In [Differential Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) (a branch of mathematics) there exists the notion of [an umbilical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilical_point). Is there a noun corresponding to the adjective *umbilical*? Could I write something like "It follows by **umbilicality** that […]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Umbilical* in this sense is an adjective, not a verb (*umbilical* is also used as a noun synonymous with *umbilical cord* in both the biological sense and several figurative senses analogous to it). In mathematics, there is the noun *umbilic* synonymous with *umbilical point*.

It is quite correct to create the noun *umbilicality* to mean the quality held by something which is umbilical, in any sense of the word. This has been done before in the mathematical sense, and in other senses at least as far back as the 17th Century (Sir Thomas Browne, *Pseudodoxia Epidemica or Enquries into very many received tenets and commonly presumed truths*, 1646).

Edit:

Looking up *umbilic* in terms of geometry, finds it given as a synonym of *umbilical point*, and of *umbilical* as it relates to those. Since in this sense there's no tendency - as there is in other senses - to favour *umbilical* for the cord and *umbilic* for anything else related to the navel, then *umbilicity* would have just as much justification as *umbilicality*. Since it's also shorter, less clumsy sounding and - most importantly of all - already used by many in this context, it would be the one to go for.

Comment: According to another thread here today, we would want *umbilicity*... but I disagree with that choice.

Comment: Thank you @John for your elaborate answer. I edited my question to change 'verb' to 'adjective'.

Comment: @GEdgar what other thread is that? *Umbilicity* would mean the quality held by a navel or belly-button. I'm not getting how you are linking the two—excuse the pun.

Comment: @GEdgar : I have also encountered *umbilicity* before, but it didn't seem right to me either. But I found it in the same context as described in my question.

Comment: @alexlo I could see how someone might arrive at *umbilicity* and if it is being used, then it may be best to use it. Now, outside of your field, *umbilicity* would mean "the quality of being umbilic" where *umbilic* means "of a navel or bellybutton" while *umbilicality* would mean "the quality of being umbilical" where *umbilical* mean "of the cord that connects the navel of a fetus or embryo to the placenta". I don't know what figurative analogy brought this into mathematics, so it's possible that both are reasonable, and if so *umbilicity* might be just as valid, though as general English...

Comment: I'd probably go for *omphalic* for *of or related to the navel*

Comment: ...words they have different meanings. Even if the analogy does not hold over into mathematics, if the term is used, you are best advised to use it too and just live with the fact that really they should have either used *umbilical* and *umbilicality* or used *umbilic* and *umbilicity*, but they didn't. It would be far from the first mixed metaphor to make it into a technical coinage, so just because in their general senses they mean different unmatched things, doesn't mean they necessarily will when used to label some new development in a field...

Comment: ...And that's even assuming the terms developed in English, rather than being translated from better-matched terms in another language. If your peers use *umbilicity* then ignore all I have to say as an English nerd about the word, and listen to the Math nerds! ;)

Comment: @Jim I generally would too not least because *omphaloskepsis* and *omphalomancy* are fun words, and omphalos stones are an interesting bit of religious history. It remains true though, that as well as that Greek-derived word we also have the Latin-derived *umbilic*. Note that the definitions are not exactly the same, *omphalic* covers both the *umbilic* and the *umbilical*, so as much as I prefer *omphalic* and have used it for real where I never have *umbilic* if I needed for some reason to be clear I was excluding the *umbilical* I would use *umbilic*. Can't see it ever coming up, though.

Comment: Oh! How silly of me! Since the Mathematical use is also using *umbilic* as a noun, then *umbilicity* is totally of equal validity in that particular sense, just derived from that noun, not from *umbilical*. It really would have been simpler if they'd used *omphalic* as per @Jim wouldn't it? ;) Again though, that applies only to this particular mathematical use.

Comment: @JonHanna I have to say though, that I encountered umbilicity only once in the notes of a classmate. And considering that neither of us is a native english speaker, I wouldn't consider his usage of *umbilicity* official in any way. It is not the case that I found the word in any formal textbook about the topic. So in my opinion *umbilicality* still sounds better and remains my "version of choice".

Comment: @JonHanna, something tells me that our fellow Edgar would take issue with _electricity_ is well. He is queer like that.

Comment: @theUg I really just don't get what the argument is, unless it's against any word unknown to Chaucer, or perhaps to the author of Beowulf.

Comment: Alexio. It might be worth just finding what your professors/teachers/tutors/etc. use. I must say this use of the word intrigues me, but alas a brief look at the mathematics shows I lack several intermediary steps to understanding it.

Comment: I'd say the noun is *navel*, the jump to *umbilical* is the first change into adjective. If you go with *umbilicality* we can follow with an adjective *umbilicalital*, then noun  *umbilicalitality*, then *umbilicalitalital*, *umbilicalitalitality*, *umbilicalitalitalital* and meta-dive like that ad nauseam.

Comment: The reference cited in this answer is not in the context of mathematics but "*umbilicality*, a word coined by Thomas Browne to describe an intimate conjunction tending towards a perfect coherence between a human being and God".

Comment: @Kris, yes I think that might well be why I said it was in another sense.

Comment: Always useful when referring to Sir Thomas Browne to state just where precisely in his vast encyclopaedia P.E. a cited neologism of his can be found. He's credited with over 800 entries of first usages in the OED.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with deriving *umbilicality* from *umbilical*. The same process generates *mortality, sexuality, speciality, personality*, for example.

I don't know much about either [obstetrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstetrics) or OP's specialised context, but I guess he wants it to mean *principles relating to "umbilical" entities/relationships in mathematics*. Nothing wrong with that either - as the above list shows, the precise meaning of the derived word isn't always exactly *the state of being xxxxx-al*.

But there's no particular grammatical/liguistic principle saying the noun "should" be *umbilical* as opposed to, say, *umbilicity*. Come to that, if we really did need a word meaning *the state of being umbilical*, *umbilicalness* would be just as valid as *umbilicality*.

Admittedly it's a bit old (1843), but this citation from OED is perhaps relevant...

> The focal hyperbola of the ellipsoid and the focal ellipse of the hyperboloid of two sheets, are **umbilicar** focals, and pass through the **umbilics** of these surfaces.

---

In short, there's no *grammatical* reason why OP can't use *umbilicality* in his context, but obviously it makes sense to use whatever word his colleagues use. A quick search on Google Books claims 96 instances of [umbilicality](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22umbilicality%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and 305 for [umbilicity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22umbilicity%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (plus 3 for [umbilicalness](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22umbilicalness%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). As I said, I'm no expert, but it looks to me as if they're all intended to mean much the same thing. I'd go with the majority.

Answer (score 1):

*Umbilicality* is a word, in the OP's context of mathematics and in mathematical physics, used to form a noun  expressing state or condition from the adjective *umbilical*.
**syn**. *umbilicity*

[emphasis mine:]

> Levi umbilicality is weaker than Euclidean **umbilicality** because it contains no information on terms of the form h(Z,W) with holomorphic Z and W. [p.1]
>   ...
>   Concerning the restriction n>=2 in the classification theorem, note that for n=1 the **umbilicality** property is satisfied by any hypersurface of C2. [p.2]

R. Monti, D. Morbidelli: Levi umbilical surfaces in complex space, 01/2006, ResearchGate [Arxiv [pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512330.pdf) 243 KB]

See also,
V Mangione [pdf](http://www.unipr.it/~mangione/Einstein-IJMMS-20421.pdf); [Xiaohuan Mo](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3admT0HNlpWbQJ%3awww.math.pku.edu.cn:8000/var/preprint/404.ps%20&cd=32&hl=en&ct=clnk);  [V BAYLE, 2003](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aHoaAnIGMQakJ%3awww.ugr.es/~crosales/profile.pdf%20&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgbIw-bWoQ0QEQVu-3FyeRNoOvb0tUL2yoJv5snLN-YHnAPWEMHJw8Xioh-a11upRv1wq0K0ANzDDh0VdqS-2a0ICIfAHEQufJy9iYEz5xE5Ke9hYPOFV2gNTVTk4XtobFSD9Vm&sig=AHIEtbTNyHPuofNwwFS45C7B5kBnthBoVQ); I Cătălin Angelo: 
Degenerate foliations of the Semi-Riemannian Manifolds, ResearchGate.